# Are comments pointing to other potentially useful resources ephemeral?

Tags: discussion, comments

Example:

[image]

Is that kind of comment subject to deletion?

Comment: A downvote means yes or no?

Comment: The confusion over what the votes on your question mean is an indication that your question is valuable and the community has opinions about it, but it's phrased in such a way as to make votes ambiguous. You can always edit and state your opinion. Then you'll know what the votes represent.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I don't believe that meta questions should necessarily take side.

Comment: I'm in favor of meta posts and discussion. If you don't care about "sides" however, why ask if the votes mean yes or no? I upvoted your post because I favor meta discussions. But a discussion without caring about resolution of some kind means little. I need to withdraw my upvote.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I asked to know what the policy is.

Comment: Ah, then I refer you to [Should answers in comments be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/378/169). Please flag when mods miss this.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks, I didn't regard a potentially useful resource as an answer though. But I understand reading your answer that they are regarded as such.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since your related link was back to the same question itself, I'm confused as to how it was helpful. To what was it linked originally?

Comment: @anongoodnurse It was meant to be linked to http://health.stackexchange.com/q/170/43

Comment: Ah, well that's more reasonable, and I'm sorry for the confusion (I really was confused). I hope someone else will weigh in on this.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, as it is posing as an answer to the question, and we can't vote on the validity of the link/information in the link, it should be deleted as an attempt to answer in comments.

Until there is a policy that answers in comments are appropriate, as a moderator, I will remove such comments (as well as the comment before it. I'll leave it up for the time being.)

This is why meta participation is so important. Unfortunately, participation in meta sort of slow here still.